# How can I exclude a specific computer from web stats?

Tags: web-development, awstats

I'm using AWStats to track visits to my site. I know how to exclude specific ip addresses from the stats (using AWStat's .conf file). But how would I just exclude one specific visitor (me)?

I want to exclude every visit regardless of my location. Just based on my specific computer, or cookies, or possibly a login password?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how this indicates I can't. This just says what I **can** do. I was hoping there was another way in addition to the SkipHosts solution.

Comment: You could filter the source awstats uses, i.e. the webserver log. Example: http://www.webmasterview.com/2009/11/apache-log-cruft/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you can

> FAQ-COM140 : HOW CAN I EXCLUDE MY IP
>
> ADDRESS (OR WHOLE SUBNET MASK) FROM
>   STATS ? PROBLEM:
>
> I don't want to see
>   my own IP address in the stats or I
>   want to exclude counting visits from a
>   whole subnet. SOLUTION: You must edit
>   the config file to change the
>   SkipHosts parameter. For example, to
>   exclude:
>
> - your own IP address 123.123.123.123, use SkipHosts="123.123.123.123"
> - the whole subnet 123.123.123.xxx, use
>     SkipHosts="REGEX[^123.123.123.]"
> - all sub hosts xxx.myintranet.com, use
>     SkipHosts="REGEX[.myintranet.com$]"
>     (This one works only if DNS lookup is
>     already done in your log file).

From http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_config.html#SkipHosts

Comment: As a little hack he could just fake the User-Agent string of his web browser and use SkipUserAgents (http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_config.html#SkipUserAgents) to identify and ignore his specific user agent.